# find nth-child after .filter()

Tags: jquery, css

I trying to set css property just for the elements that display!=none

this works for the first child after using .filter()

```
$("#container > li").filter(':not(:hidden)').first().css("margin-right", "0");
```

but I want to set also for nth-child(3n+1) and this won't work because it count also the hidden elements when calculate the nth-child

```
 $("#container > li:nth-child(3n+1)").filter(':not(:hidden)').css("margin-right","0");
```

I also tried

```
$("#container > li").filter(':not(:hidden)').find(':nth-child(3n+1)').css("margin-right", "0");
```

any idea how to set css for every 4 child after filter those who not hidden?

is there a selector like .first() for nth-child()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach (targeting each 4th element in the collection returned by first `filter` call):

```
$("#container > li")
   .filter(':visible')
   .filter(function(i) {
     return (i + 1) % 4 === 0; 
   })
   .css('margin-right', '0');
```

Comment: Why is `===` explicitly necessary? `(i + 1) % 4` will always return an integer.

Comment: @ItayGrudev One word - [linter](http://www.jshint.com/). Our style guide prevents any usage of `==` - and we're definitely not alone in this. ) Of course, one can override it with comments if _really_ necessary, but this is just not that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#container > li:visible").css("margin-right", function(i) {
    return i%3 ? null : 0;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/e9NU3/2/)